# ASP.net MVC 3 route for jpg files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, iis-7.5, jpeg

I have an MVC 3 application with this route in global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProfilePictureSmall",                             // Route name
            "small/{PictureID}.jpg",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Picture", action = "Show", Size = "small", PictureID = Guid.Empty }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

And this is the action from my controller

```
public ActionResult Show(string Size, Guid PictureID)
```

This route isn't working on my computer but it works on other local computers and test servers and live servers.
It used to work on my PC as well, but I recently reinstalled my system so I assume it has something to do with this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

PS: All other routes work fine.
This one also works if I remove **.jpg**

Comment: What version of IIS are you running on your machine? Ensure that you are running the site in the same environment as everyone else.

Comment: I have IIS 7.5.7600.16385, exactly like the test/live machines and other local machines

Comment: I suspect this is IIS routing it incorrectly. As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971203/how-to-route-to-css-js-files-in-mvc-net an HTTP handler might be a method to take?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but given the fact that the code works on many other machines (as it did on mine before reinstalling the system) I suspect it to be a IIS config problem

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem. (with MVC 4)

Comment: Sorry .. but I haven't found one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work by re installing IIS.

I don't know what I did exactly, but here are the features I've checked when installing IIS on Windows 7
Control Panel / Turn on-off Windows Features / Internet Information services

These are the only changes I've made (no code/config changes)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For me, adding this line to web.config inside system.webServer

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

fixed it.

Btw. I'm using .Net MVC 4.0

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951962/973485)

Comment: I Already have that set. I'm using MVC 3.0. I'll probably migrate to MVC 4 in the near future

Comment: Have you also tried setting?
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true

Comment: That I haven't. The weird thing is that the same code (including config files) works fine on many other machines. That's why I'm guessing it has to do with my IIS configuration or something like that

Comment: Strange... /small/{PictureID}.jpg - Does those files exist physically on that on that location? If so, routes.RouteExistingFiles = true is nessersarry. When you say it's not working does it ignore your route and just show the original image, or give you an error?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is fresh install of Windows, the .NET Framework may have been installed before IIS and may not be registered correctly so the static file handler may be trying to serve up a jpg that does not exist.

Try running `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`