# How to show byte[] array image with name and format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using following function to display byte[] array image in asp.net mvc

```
        public ActionResult Images(int id)
        {
            byte[] imageData = GetImage(id);

            string contentType = "image/jpeg";

            return File(imageData, contentType);
        }

        <img src="/Home/Images/2">
```

So Problem is this i don't want to show **/Home/Images/2** . I want to show any random name with image format like this

```
        > /Home/Images/imgnameetc.jpg
```

Note:
I have image just byte[] array form.No any other information like name ,image format

I did search on it but i can't found any solution

Please help.

Comment: are you talking about the *url you navigate to* ? or *how the file identifies itself if saved* ? They are 2 different things...

Comment: it is possible, but if you want to pass any random name then how you are going to track the image id and get the bytes for specific image?

Answer (score 1):

Your server-side code can't spoof the url that the user navigated to. If they navigated to `/Home/Images/2`, then ***that is the url***. What you *can* do is have them navigate to `/Home/Images/imgnameetc.jpg` *instead of* `/Home/Images/2`, but then you will need to configure the routes to allow names instead of an id, and have somewhere where you can lookup the details from a name (/slug) instead of from an id. For example, you might have a `UrlSlug` column in your database which is indexed (I would suggest unique and non-clustered, with a restriction to non-null values, and including the id as an additional included value (not part of the index, but available for slug => id queries) which contains `imgnameetc.jpg` for that record, so you can find it with a simple `where` test.

One other thing you can do is set the *content-disposition* header, which tells the browser how the file identifies itself; for example, setting the `"content-disposition"` header to `"inline;filename=imgnameetc.jpg"` *may* help if the user tries to save the file; however, it ***will not*** change the url shown in the browser.

Comment: both solutions are valid but i cant change database now.is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The route table must be configured to accept an image's name in the URL. And wherever you are storing the image, you can store the name along with it. A separate column incase of database.

In register routes method of Global.asax, try writing this.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          "ImageRoute", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{imageName}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Images", imageName = UrlParameter.Optional       });
```

EX url = localhost/Home/Images/image1.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following URL,
You can achieve this with the help of MVC Routers. Just add one router specific to your request and configure your IIS for it.

**[Image with name and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587541/asp-net-mvc-3-route-for-jpg-files)**